# Installing DD-WRT on Dlink dir-600 rev b2

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, dd-wrt

I have a problem installing dd-wrt on my router 2.17 firmware ver, i tried installing via web interface, it says image is not recognized, and i tried using room emergency too, but the weird things its just restarted and not installing any firmware, any idea or suggestion how?

Comment: Study the DD WRT Wiki and check if the specific hardware revision is supported or not. I assume you are first flashing the  Factory to DD WRT firmware first. The filename will have the  word 'factory' in it. If one specific firmware version does not work, try a previous build. Also you might need to try thru different browsers. Come what may have original stock firmware ready with you in case things go wrong. Then you may need to access the emergency room if available to flash the stock firmware back.

Comment: Don't download images from the router database, they are buggy and aren't updated, you can brick the router with them. Only download images from the ftp site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the response,after long research and trial error i have a solution for this! Actually i need downgrade to 2.10 using middle firmware first, and then to 2.05 after that i can flash ddnwrt without problem